# Unable to store CLOB data in to CLOB defined column in DB2

Tags: database, db2, clob

It's a repeated issue i guess, but couldn't find a proper solution yet.  Basically I am trying to insert bit huge XML i.e. 32000+ characters in to a CLOB column through ***DB2*** procedure.  Insertion is failing with the below error looks DB2 is considering the input as String rather than CLOB datatype.  Can you please suggest what needs to be done?

SP

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE logging (IN HEADERDATA CLOB(10M))
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Logging(Header) VALUES (HEADERDATA);
    COMMIT;
END
```

Error

```
The string constant beginning with 
"'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><XXXXXXXX xmlns:xsi="http:" is too long.. 
SQLCODE=-102, SQLSTATE=54002, DRIVER=XXXXXX
```

Comment: Please show how you call your stored procedure.

Comment: CALL logging ('<<data with 40000 char>>')

Comment: and running this anonymous block in IBM data-studio. JFYI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Character literals in DB2 are limited to about 32K bytes. To handle larger LOBs you need to avoid having to use SQL literal values.

One way to do this without extra programming is write your [future] CLOB contents to a file and use `IMPORT` or `LOAD` to insert its contents into a column.

Alternatively, you could wrap a simple Java program around your procedure call where you would use `PreparedStatement.setClob()` to handle your large XML document.

Comment: Thanks, I am able to run with the host variable like CALL logging ('?').  Will try with Java code like you said and revert.