# DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-433, SQLSTATE=22001 when inserting Base64 CLOB data

Tags: db2

DB2 exception - DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-433, SQLSTATE=22001 is thrown when inserting a Base64 CLOB data with length of 38K characters into DB2 table CLOB field defined with length of 10MB. Database insertion is done via a Stored Procedure called by a MuleSoft flow. We've been unable to find the root cause or solution to this. Has anyone seen this behaviour?

Comment: This may be more appropriate on http://dba.stackexchange.com/ if you are not doing any software development when you encounter this.

Comment: Thanks for the information, Chris, I'll also post the issue on dba stackexchange. We have developed the solution (i.e. the MuleSoft flows and the Stored Procedure and the DB2 database).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to store CLOB data in to CLOB defined column in DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44871254/unable-to-store-clob-data-in-to-clob-defined-column-in-db2)