# How to insert large CSV into a CLOB column with DB2/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, db2, clob

Problem: I have a large CSV that i want to insert into DB2 table with Rails

Description: The CSV is about 2k lines/8K characters. The CLOB column is set up to handle over 10K characters. I can insert the CSV just fine though RubyMine database console. However my app crashes.

ActiveRecord produces one huge insert query. Code:

```
Logger.create(csv: csv_data.to_s)
```

DB2 returns an error:

```
 ActiveRecord::JDBCError: [SQL0102] String constant beginning with 'foobar' too long.
```

I can insert huge PDF files into BLOB columns just fine using similar code. I tried creating the record first and then updating it with data, no difference.

This problem is the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44871254/unable-to-store-clob-data-in-to-clob-defined-column-in-db2). Except I need a Rails solution, rather than general one

Comment: What is the DB2 codeset/codepage/territory?  What is the application codepage? Does the CSV contain non-ASCII values being converted to UTF-8  ? What is the DB2-server operating-system?  What is the DB2-server version? Is the target table a nickname?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to store CLOB data in to CLOB defined column in DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44871254/unable-to-store-clob-data-in-to-clob-defined-column-in-db2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a hack around this by splitting the `csv_data` into chunks and appending them to the column

```
update_attribute(:csv, '') if self.csv.nil? # Can't CONCAT to nil

# Split csv_data into chunks, concatenate each one to the field
csv_data.scan(/.{1,6144}/m).each do |part|
  parm =  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote(part)
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("update #{Logger.table_name} set csv = CONCAT(csv, #{parm}) where id = #{self.id}")
end
```